# How to have InputFormTextBox toolbar available in Ribbon in Visual Webpart?

Tags: visual-web-part, inputformtextbox

How to have InputFormTextBox toolbar available in Ribbon in VIsual Webpart?
Whenever I add following markup in control, it displays toolbar above the field.

```
<SharePoint:InputFormTextBox ID="rftDefaultValue" RichText="true" 
RichTextMode="FullHtml" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5"
Width="100%"></SharePoint:InputFormTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar is displayed because you set `RichText="true"` and `TextMode="MultiLine"`

if you wont use one line set the TextMode property to `SingleLine` or if you multiline but remove the toolbar a set the RichText property to `false`

Comment: Thank you Nizar Grindi for your reply but I didn't ask how to hide it. I asked how to show toolbar in Ribbon like other OOTB webparts do.